# Confidence Interval information in Figure (legend?)

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I´m using seaborn (which is based on matplotlib) to plot some graphs.
Currently, I´m plotting a barplot (in seaborn it is called factorplot) which also prints a 0,95 confidence interval.
I would like to add the information, that it is a 95% confidence interval, to the figure, for instance in the legend.
Is there any way to include this information, so that I don´t have to mention it in my text?

Answer (score 0):

I actually was just having this issue too...

What I came up with is a bit hackish, as it appears that the `sns._BarPlotter` instance that does all the confidence interval calculations is not exposed to the user.

However, we can create one of these ourselves, using the same parameters that we would use for `sns.barplot()`, keeping in mind that you have to explicitly supply the parameters that are often left as defaults. Since we're not plotting with this (although we could, theoretically), the most important parameters are the data, `ci`, and `n_boot` (number of bootstrapping iterations):

```py
from seaborn.categorical import _BarPlotter
bp = _BarPlotter(x='xdata',y='ydata',
                 hue='h',
                 data=df,
                 palette=['#C24D52','#4A70B0'],
                 ci=95,
                 n_boot=5000,
                 units=None,
                 order=None, 
                 hue_order=None,
                 estimator=np.mean, 
                 orient=None, 
                 color=None,
                 saturation=0.75, 
                 errcolor='.26')
```

Once you have your `_BarPlotter`, you can access it's properties, such as the calculated confidence intervals:

```
 In[1]: bp.confint

Out[1]: array([[[ 2.06522099,  2.41611633],
                [ 2.20088709,  2.54810739],
                [        nan,         nan]],

               [[ 1.83258433,  2.3521511 ],
                [ 2.21361428,  2.64342349],
                [        nan,         nan]],

               [[ 1.30160209,  1.54427938],
                [ 1.99597604,  2.22272918],
                [        nan,         nan]],

               [[        nan,         nan],
                [        nan,         nan],
                [ 0.58609489,  0.83233859]]])
```

If this is something used frequently enough, it might be worth a fork of `seaborn` in order to expose this functionality. I've also submitted a [feature request](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/655) in the same spirit to the developers.